# Typhoon inject property

Tags: ios, objective-c, inject, typhoon

I have problems with injecting BOOL property.

I've tried next:

```
- (id)emotionControllerWithItem:(MDDiaryItem *)item firstController:(BOOL)isFirst
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[MDEmotionViewController class]
                          configuration: ^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
                [definition useInitializer:@selector(initWithAnalytics:) parameters: ^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {
                    [initializer injectParameterWith:[_services analytics]];
                }];
                [definition injectProperty:@selector(setItem:) with:item];
                [definition injectProperty:@selector(setFirstController:) with:[NSNumber numberWithBool:isFirst]];
            }];
}
```

But it crashes in runtime with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Actually it is nothing about BOOL property but injection properties with values itself. It looks like my assumption about `Typhoon` usage is wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?  Doesn't compile?  Runtime error?  Unexpected behaviour?

Comment: NB: See answer from @Aleksey, and note that with Typhoon 2.1.2 (pushed just now) it will detect if you've defined primitive runtime args, fail early, and suggest a solution. .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Runtime arguments must be always an object - not primitive type!

The correct assembly is here:

```
- (id)emotionControllerWithItem:(MDDiaryItem *)item firstController:(NSNumber *)isFirst
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[MDEmotionViewController class]
                          configuration: ^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
                [definition useInitializer:@selector(initWithAnalytics:) parameters: ^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {
                    [initializer injectParameterWith:[_services analytics]];
                }];
                [definition injectProperty:@selector(setItem:) with:item];
                [definition injectProperty:@selector(setFirstController:) with:isFirst];
            }];
}
```

where firstController property can has BOOL, but when calling assmebly interface, you have to use NSNumber wrapper:

```
[assembly emotionControllerWithItem:item firstController:@YES];
```

Comment: Aleksey, is this limitation on Typhoon or objective-c? I don't understand where from error comes

Comment: It's limitation of Typhoon. Typhoon required to pass all values to inject as objects. Now we added argument type checking and raise an exception when primitive runtime argument usage.

Comment: Also note, that Typhoon, similar to KVC unwrap values into primitive, if destination has primitive type. (all primitive values are supported, see https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/issues/201)

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can inject as follows:

```
[definition injectProperty:@selector(isFirst) with:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
```

But probably nicer:

```
[definition injectProperty:@selector(isFirst) with:@(YES)];
```

**However, runtime arguments have the following limitations:**

- You can't call any methods on the runtime argument.
- Run-time arguments can't be primitives.

You could either work-around this, or drop back to writing your own factory class to be used in place of the assembly interface.

The answer by @Aleksey shows a workaround.

Comment: NB: The docs did not define this limitation clearly - we've corrected that.

Comment: Jasper, you pass selector for getter. Is this correct?

Comment: @EugenMartynov I usually use the getter selector (aka the property name), but you can use either.